# How to change Apple ID associated with IPA file?

Tags: ios, crash, metadata, itunes, ipa

I have an app's .IPA file which I'm trying to push to another device; however, when opening the app after installation, it asks me to sign-in to the Apple ID that was used to purchase the app. I don't have access to the Apple ID it is asking for. Is there a way I can edit the .IPA file to change the apple id required to open the app?

**Things I've tried**:

1. Changing the .IPA file to .zip, then deleting the metadata.plst file
2. Editing the metadata.plst file and changing the apple id key

**Result**:
When doing either of those things, the app opens then crashes immediately, and this time, doesn't ask for an apple id

**Things to consider**

1. Retrieving the Apple Id that is currently associated with the app is not an option. It is not mine.
2. The app is no longer in the App Store

I'm starting to doubt that there is even a solution. Any help or feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: If you could do what you are describing you could steal the app. Obviously that is just what Apple is preventing.

Comment: There is no solution.  The original AppleID is used in the DRM process used when the app is purchased.  You can't simply change it.

Answer (score 2):

I did it this way, opened the iTunesMetadata.plist directly from the archive without unpacking it, changed the appleid and updated the archive. Everything worked great with no errors.